# Seq[(Int,Int)] with nulls implicitly converted to DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, null, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple test case that convert a `Seq[(Int,Int)]` to a DataFrame:

```
test("SparkTest 0280") {
  val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage", "false").set("spark.sql.cbo.enabled", "true")
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).master("local").appName("SparkTest").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  Seq[(Int,Int)]((null, 1), (2, null), (null, 3)).toDF("a", "b").createOrReplaceTempView("t")
  spark.sql("select a,b,nvl(a,b) from t").show(truncate = false)
}
```

There is a compiling problem:

```
Error:(565, 21) an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion
    Seq[(Int,Int)]((null, 1), (2, null), (null, 3)).toDF("a", "b").createOrReplaceTempView("t")
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `null` directly like this since the created column would be of type `Any` (not allowed for dataframes). This can be confirmed by creating a RDD:

```
val rdd: RDD[(Any, Any)] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((null, 1), (2, null), (null, 3)))
```

This is due to `Int` being non-nullable in Scala, from the [Scala tour](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html):

> There are nine predefined value types and they are non-nullable: `Double`, `Float`, `Long`, `Int`, `Short`, `Byte`, `Char`, `Unit`, and `Boolean`.

Columns with other datatypes (such as strings) can be created with `null` directly, otherwise an easy solution would be to use `None` and `Some`:

```
Seq((None, Some(1)), (Some(2), None), (None, Some(3))).toDF("a", "b"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `nulls` you should replace `Ints` with `java.lang.Integers`:

```
Seq[(Integer, Integer)]((null, 1), (2, null), (null, 3)).toDF("a", "b")
// org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: int]
```

which are nullable.

Comment: Yes,thank you, kind of not flexible for scala value type in dealing with nulls